# Python: How do i convert non numeric character into blank space

Tags: python, pandas

I have already gone through the given solutions, but i was not able to understand the concept.
I have a data with 3 columns, and the data is really huge. One of my columns consists of alphanumeric names like e.g apple 4014, orange 40mg/10. Can anyone help me to write a function that takes column of a dataframe and convert all the character other than alphabets to blank spaces.
I have this product description as column name. So can I import the whole column so as to convert all the fields under product description to text only. This is just the dummy data.

[image]

Comment: Please add your dummy data

Comment: Break it down into smaller steps. Can you do the same kind of work on a single string? Show us what you have tried to solve this problem so far.

Comment: i cant post my whole data but a data similar to that i am posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by regex - all non alphabet values extracted by `[^a-zA-Z]+`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["apple 4014", "orange 40mg/10"]})

df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ')
print (df)
            a
0      apple 
1  orange mg
```

Or:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]+', '')
print (df)
          a
0     apple
1  orangemg
```

Comment: can i directly add my column in the place of apple and orange so all of my data can be converted directly